# Versioning Major releases

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app and publishing it in Google Market. The problem is that the difference between v1.x and v2.x is huge, and like most products I wouldn't like to automatically provide Major upgrade for free for user of v1.

Is there any way to "separate" the payment for v1 and v2, and provide "upgrade license" for users of v1?

I must say admins on this forum are idiots, closed for a reason: "Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way". How is it not related to software development? :)

Comment: Not every question about creating software is programming related. In this case the question is how to deal with upgrades in the android market. Unless you plan on *programming* the change of behavior to the android market, this is off-topic. Also, the question was certainly not closed by us "idiot admins". We're called moderators and generally react when the community asks us to, through flags. In this case, however, your question was closed by the community itself, in other words, other non-"idiots", non-"admins".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrades nope; kind of irritating that the market has no option for coupon codes or developer discounts etc. but that's the way it currently is.

Kind of a hack, but you could leave the name the same and add Pro or Plus and change your package name so for instance

com.myapplication.v1

becomes

com.myapplication.v2

Then to promote it you can use admobs inhouse promotion facility (assuming you have put admob v1) it's not perfect but it would work, then just turn on the add when you are ready with a new version.

An alternative is to structure the newer application so that the new features are in app payments, that would probably be the most user friendly approach, let them use them for N days then shut them down and offer the users the ability to pay for the newer features

I have also not looked at their licensing service much, it might be possible to do something with that I suppose but I suspect not.